# Joomla Remove GET PRO version for $37

Tags: joomla

I have problem with joomla . In article page there is an image named **GET PRO version for $37** . How to remove this. 
In    components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php , a variable name **$this->item->text;**. When Remove this variable the picture and content also removed. How to remove this image only.

Comment: Go to admin remove the image from article content.

Answer (score 0):

Login to **/administrator**.

Select `Content->Article Manager`. You will see a list of articles similar to this:
[image: Joomla 2.5 Article Manager]

Find the article you want, click on it's name in the list, this will open up the editor, and look similar to this:
[image: Joomla 2.5 Article Editor]

Click on the offending image, and press `delete`

Click on one of the "Save" buttons to save your changes, they're in the toolbar in the top right:
[image: Joomla 2.5 Article Editor Toolbar buttons]

Answer (score -1):

use preg_match code

```
preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i',$this->item->text, $matches);
```

After use this code easily remove the image tag form article

Comment: This will remove all images from article content! Its a bad idea

Comment: Oh my, not sure how you could recommend this